# SublimeText: When the lines are longer than the width of the screen

Tags: sublimetext2, settings, sublimetext, application-settings

When the lines are longer than the width of the screen, SublimeText, by default, forces the end of the line to be displayed on a second line.

[image]

Is there a way to tell SublimeText to not do that? I'd like the whole line to remain on one line and have a horizontal scroll bar.

I am using SublimeText 2 Version 2.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"word_wrap": false` in your User Preferences

Answer (score 1):

You could also add the following to your user key-bindings file (*Preferences* -> *Key Bindings - User*) to add a key or a key combination to toggle between the two modes. I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, but the key combination could be anything you want.

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+w"],
    "command": "toggle_setting",
    "args":
    {
        "setting": "word_wrap"
    }
}
```